# Deleting SMS in inbox

Tags: android, sms, message

How can we delete a single SMS from the inbox, I've tried the code below but it still erased all.

```
Cursor c = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().
query(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address", "person","date", "body" }, null, null, null);
try {
while (c.moveToNext()) {
int id = c.getInt(0);
String address = c.getString(2);
if(address.equals(address)){
getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/" + id),null, null);} 
}
}catch(Exception e){
 }
```

Comment: Look at your if condition, you are matching same address which you are getting from the cursor.

Comment: then how do can only delete one sms.

Answer (score 0):

@user3739864 Try this;

```
try {
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
    int id = c.getInt(0);
    String address = c.getString(2);

    if(id == // the id you want to delete ){
        getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/" +             id),null, null);} 
    }

} catch(Exception e){
}
```